# How can I implement file exporting (xlsx,pdf,csv,etc) in jQuery datatables with java on server side?

Tags: java, spring-boot, datatables

I am new to  Spring Boot and creating a Project where I am trying to export the data available on datatable to required file type  (xlsx,pdf,csv,etc) and I want to achieve this by server side process. There are lot of blogs available for file exporting  on internet but is there any specific way to do this with datatables ?

Comment: DataTables runs in the browser. If you are using DataTables' server-side processing then the complete set of data does not exist in the DataTable (at least, it shouldn't - otherwise you have defeated the purpose of using server-side processing). Therefore, you have to find a server-side solution (in your case, based on Spring, I expect). DataTables is not going to help you with that, as it only contains a subset of the overall data.

Comment: Thank you andrew for this info. I am using server side processing and wasted my time in finding client side solution.

Comment: You may already be aware of this: The alternative is to stop using `serverSide: true` (assuming you do not have so much data that this becomes too slow for DataTables to handle). Then you will be able to take advantage of the DataTables [buttons extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/). That extension provides full support for exporting to all the file formats you mention in the question.